# Getting "EntityValidationError" while trying to store hashed data in database

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, encryption, hash

I'm trying to create a register form in ASP.net using Entity Framework. The registering works fine without trying to hash the data but when I try to hash the data I am getting the following error: "EntityValidationErrors".

**Encryption classes**

```
public class Encrypt
{
    public static string GetMD5Hash(string input)
    {
        using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider()) {
            byte[] b = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            b = md5.ComputeHash(b);
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte x in b)
            {
                sb.Append(x.ToString("x2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

**And**

```
public class CustomPasswordHasher : IPasswordHasher
{
    public string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        return Encrypt.GetMD5Hash(password);
    }

    public PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
    {
        if (hashedPassword == HashPassword(providedPassword))
        {
            return PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
        }
    }
}
```

**Method where I'm trying to encrypt my data**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(CustomUser user)
    {
        CustomPasswordHasher cph = new CustomPasswordHasher();
        var hashedpw = cph.HashPassword(user.Password);
        user.Password = hashedpw;

        using (DBModelEntities dbModel = new DBModelEntities())
        {
            if (dbModel.CustomUsers.Any(x => x.Email == user.Email))
            {
                ViewBag.DuplicateMessage = "Email already in use";
                return View("Register", user);
            }

            dbModel.CustomUsers.Add(user);
            dbModel.SaveChanges();
        }

        ModelState.Clear();
        ViewBag.SuccesMessage = "Succes";
        return View("Register", new customUser());
    }
```

**And my CustomUserModel class**

```
public partial class CustomUser
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Verplicht")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Verplicht")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Verplicht")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string LoginErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Hope someone can help me figure this out!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please make sure the datatype defined in DB and the character you are trying insert is with the range which is defined

Comment: Check the length of the Password column in the db.

Comment: My password column named "Password" is nvarchar(MAX).

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the exact error message

```
 catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", 
                                        validationError.PropertyName, 
                                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for helping. I figured it out, i hashed my first password but not my confirm password. Due to this those 2 passwords were not equal and my application prevented this to be written to the database.